# NHibernate LINQ Contains doesn't work

Tags: linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am new to NHibernate and working with FluentNhibernate for a new project. I came accross a strange issue when executing a very simple linq query.

Query 1 - Works very well

```
      //Query 1
          var customers = from customer in _session.Query<Customer>() 
                        where customer.FirstName == "john"
                        select new
                        {
                            customer.FirstName,
                            customer.LastName
                        };
```

When below query 2 is executed I get an error "Could not execute query"

```
       //Query 2.
           var customers = from customer in _session.Query<Customer>() 
                         where customer.FirstName.Contains("john")
                        select new
                        {
                            customer.FirstName,
                            customer.LastName
                        };
```

The NH generated query is,

select customer0_.FirstName as col_0_0_, customer0_.LastName as col_1_0_ 
from tblCustomer customer0_ 
where customer0_.FirstName like ('%'||@p0||'%');@p0 = 'john'

it has generated **FirstName like ('%'||@p0||'%')** instead of **FirstName like ('%'+@p0+'%')** as I can understand.

The database I am using is SQLServerCE and the NHibernate version is 3.1.0

Please help resolving this issue.

Comment: What version of NHibernate are you using?

Comment: Is it not possible that `||` is *an option* for string concatenation in the SQL dialect you're using? What database are you using? Does the query actually fail?

Comment: I am using NHibernate v 3.1.0

Comment: I am using SQL Server embedded edition and the query fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the definition of concat function in "Dialect.cs" file (base dialect class of NH):

```
RegisterFunction("concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(NHibernateUtil.String, "(", "||", ")"));
```

Which should be

```
RegisterFunction("concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(NHibernateUtil.String, "(", "+", ")"));
```

for SQL CE.
So you have to use MsSqlCe40Dialect class.
I think it's not registered in the fluent-NHibernate yet, so you can define it this way:

```
... MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard  
                      ...  
                      .Dialect<MsSqlCe40Dialect>();
```

Also there is a patch for the rest of missing functions, waiting for approval:
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2723
Please vote!

In the meantime you can create your own dialect:

```
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Dialect;
using NHibernate.Dialect.Function;

namespace Test1
{
    public class TempSqlCeDialect : MsSqlCeDialect
    {
        public TempSqlCeDialect()
        {
            RegisterFunction("concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(NHibernateUtil.String, "(", "+", ")"));
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can use it by defining:

```
... MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard.Dialect<TempSqlCeDialect>() ...
```

Comment: Changed the dialect to MsSqlCe40Dialect but it is still not working. Do I have to wait till that bug is fixed or?

Comment: I've edited my last post to add "TempSqlCeDialect". It should solve the problem.